# First two fragment shader outputs are different

Tags: ios, glsl, gpuimage, fragment-shader, glsles

I'm currently trying to get this bokeh shader to work with GPUImage: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?237488-GLSL-depth-of-field-with-bokeh-v2-4-(update)

This is what I've got at the moment:

```
precision mediump float;

varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate2;
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;
uniform float inputImageTextureWidth;
uniform float inputImageTextureHeight;

#define PI 3.14159265

float width = inputImageTextureWidth; //texture width
float height = inputImageTextureHeight; //texture height

vec2 texel = vec2(1.0/width,1.0/height);

//uniform variables from external script

uniform float focalDepth;  //focal distance value in meters, but you may use autofocus option below
uniform float focalLength; //focal length in mm
uniform float fstop; //f-stop value
bool showFocus = false; //show debug focus point and focal range (red = focal point, green = focal range)

float znear = 0.1; //camera clipping start
float zfar = 5.0; //camera clipping end

//------------------------------------------
//user variables

int samples = 3; //samples on the first ring
int rings = 3; //ring count

bool manualdof = false; //manual dof calculation
float ndofstart = 1.0; //near dof blur start
float ndofdist = 2.0; //near dof blur falloff distance
float fdofstart = 1.0; //far dof blur start
float fdofdist = 3.0; //far dof blur falloff distance

float CoC = 0.03;//circle of confusion size in mm (35mm film = 0.03mm)

bool vignetting = false; //use optical lens vignetting?
float vignout = 1.3; //vignetting outer border
float vignin = 0.0; //vignetting inner border
float vignfade = 22.0; //f-stops till vignete fades

bool autofocus = false; //use autofocus in shader? disable if you use external focalDepth value
vec2 focus = vec2(0.5, 0.5); // autofocus point on screen (0.0,0.0 - left lower corner, 1.0,1.0 - upper right)
float maxblur = 1.0; //clamp value of max blur (0.0 = no blur,1.0 default)

float threshold = 0.5; //highlight threshold;
float gain = 2.0; //highlight gain;

float bias = 0.5; //bokeh edge bias
float fringe = 0.7; //bokeh chromatic aberration/fringing

bool noise = false; //use noise instead of pattern for sample dithering
float namount = 0.0001; //dither amount

bool depthblur = false; //blur the depth buffer?
float dbsize = 1.25; //depthblursize

/*
 next part is experimental
 not looking good with small sample and ring count
 looks okay starting from samples = 4, rings = 4
 */

bool pentagon = false; //use pentagon as bokeh shape?
float feather = 0.4; //pentagon shape feather

//------------------------------------------


float penta(vec2 coords) //pentagonal shape
{
    float scale = float(rings) - 1.3;
    vec4  HS0 = vec4( 1.0,         0.0,         0.0,  1.0);
    vec4  HS1 = vec4( 0.309016994, 0.951056516, 0.0,  1.0);
    vec4  HS2 = vec4(-0.809016994, 0.587785252, 0.0,  1.0);
    vec4  HS3 = vec4(-0.809016994,-0.587785252, 0.0,  1.0);
    vec4  HS4 = vec4( 0.309016994,-0.951056516, 0.0,  1.0);
    vec4  HS5 = vec4( 0.0        ,0.0         , 1.0,  1.0);

    vec4  one = vec4( 1.0 );

    vec4 P = vec4((coords),vec2(scale, scale));

    vec4 dist = vec4(0.0);
    float inorout = -4.0;

    dist.x = dot( P, HS0 );
    dist.y = dot( P, HS1 );
    dist.z = dot( P, HS2 );
    dist.w = dot( P, HS3 );

    dist = smoothstep( -feather, feather, dist );

    inorout += dot( dist, one );

    dist.x = dot( P, HS4 );
    dist.y = HS5.w - abs( P.z );

    dist = smoothstep( -feather, feather, dist );
    inorout += dist.x;

    return clamp( inorout, 0.0, 1.0 );
}

float bdepth(vec2 coords) //blurring depth
{
    float d = 0.0;
    float kernel[9];
    vec2 offset[9];

    vec2 wh = vec2(texel.x, texel.y) * dbsize;

    offset[0] = vec2(-wh.x,-wh.y);
    offset[1] = vec2( 0.0, -wh.y);
    offset[2] = vec2( wh.x -wh.y);

    offset[3] = vec2(-wh.x,  0.0);
    offset[4] = vec2( 0.0,   0.0);
    offset[5] = vec2( wh.x,  0.0);

    offset[6] = vec2(-wh.x, wh.y);
    offset[7] = vec2( 0.0,  wh.y);
    offset[8] = vec2( wh.x, wh.y);

    kernel[0] = 1.0/16.0;   kernel[1] = 2.0/16.0;   kernel[2] = 1.0/16.0;
    kernel[3] = 2.0/16.0;   kernel[4] = 4.0/16.0;   kernel[5] = 2.0/16.0;
    kernel[6] = 1.0/16.0;   kernel[7] = 2.0/16.0;   kernel[8] = 1.0/16.0;


    for( int i=0; i<9; i++ )
    {
        float tmp = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, coords + offset[i]).r;
        d += tmp * kernel[i];
    }

    return d;
}


vec3 color(vec2 coords,float blur) //processing the sample
{
    vec3 col = vec3(0.0);

    col.r = texture2D(inputImageTexture, coords + vec2(0.0,1.0)*texel*fringe*blur).r;
    col.g = texture2D(inputImageTexture, coords + vec2(-0.866,-0.5)*texel*fringe*blur).g;
    col.b = texture2D(inputImageTexture, coords + vec2(0.866,-0.5)*texel*fringe*blur).b;

    vec3 lumcoeff = vec3(0.299,0.587,0.114);
    float lum = dot(col.rgb, lumcoeff);
    float thresh = max((lum-threshold)*gain, 0.0);
    return col+mix(vec3(0.0),col,thresh*blur);
}

vec2 rand(vec2 coord) //generating noise/pattern texture for dithering
{
    float noiseX = ((fract(1.0-coord.s*(width/2.0))*0.25)+(fract(coord.t*(height/2.0))*0.75))*2.0-1.0;
    float noiseY = ((fract(1.0-coord.s*(width/2.0))*0.75)+(fract(coord.t*(height/2.0))*0.25))*2.0-1.0;

    if (noise)
    {
        noiseX = clamp(fract(sin(dot(coord ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453),0.0,1.0)*2.0-1.0;
        noiseY = clamp(fract(sin(dot(coord ,vec2(12.9898,78.233)*2.0)) * 43758.5453),0.0,1.0)*2.0-1.0;
    }
    return vec2(noiseX,noiseY);
}

vec3 debugFocus(vec3 col, float blur, float depth)
{
    float edge = 0.002*depth; //distance based edge smoothing
    float m = clamp(smoothstep(0.0,edge,blur),0.0,1.0);
    float e = clamp(smoothstep(1.0-edge,1.0,blur),0.0,1.0);

    col = mix(col,vec3(1.0,1.0,0.0),(1.0-m)*0.6);
    col = mix(col,vec3(0.0,1.0,1.0),((1.0-e)-(1.0-m))*0.2);

    return col;
}

float linearize(float depth)
{
    return -zfar * znear / (depth * (zfar - znear) - zfar);
}

float vignette()
{
    float dist = distance(textureCoordinate.xy, vec2(0.5,0.5));
    dist = smoothstep(vignout+(fstop/vignfade), vignin+(fstop/vignfade), dist);
    return clamp(dist,0.0,1.0);
}

void main()
{
    //scene depth calculation

    float depth = linearize(texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate2.xy).x);

    if (depthblur)
    {
        depth = linearize(bdepth(textureCoordinate2.xy));
    }

    //focal plane calculation

    float fDepth = focalDepth;

    if (autofocus)
    {
        fDepth = linearize(texture2D(inputImageTexture2, focus).x);
    }

    //dof blur factor calculation

    float blur = 0.0;

    if (manualdof)
    {
        float a = depth-fDepth; //focal plane
        float b = (a-fdofstart)/fdofdist; //far DoF
        float c = (-a-ndofstart)/ndofdist; //near Dof
        blur = (a>0.0)?b:c;
    }

    else
    {
        float f = focalLength; //focal length in mm
        float d = fDepth*1000.0; //focal plane in mm
        float o = depth*1000.0; //depth in mm

        float a = (o*f)/(o-f);
        float b = (d*f)/(d-f);
        float c = (d-f)/(d*fstop*CoC);

        blur = abs(a-b)*c;
    }

    blur = clamp(blur,0.0,1.0);

    // calculation of pattern for ditering

    vec2 noise = rand(textureCoordinate.xy)*namount*blur;

    // getting blur x and y step factor

    float w = (1.0/width)*blur*maxblur+noise.x;
    float h = (1.0/height)*blur*maxblur+noise.y;

    // calculation of final color

    vec3 col = vec3(0.0);

    if(blur < 0.05) //some optimization thingy
    {
        col = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate.xy).rgb;
    }

    else
    {
        col = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate.xy).rgb;
        float s = 1.0;
        int ringsamples;

        for (int i = 1; i <= rings; i += 1)
        {
            ringsamples = i * samples;

            for (int j = 0 ; j < ringsamples ; j += 1)
            {
                float step = PI*2.0 / float(ringsamples);
                float pw = (cos(float(j)*step)*float(i));
                float ph = (sin(float(j)*step)*float(i));
                float p = 1.0;
                if (pentagon)
                {
                    p = penta(vec2(pw,ph));
                }
                col += color(textureCoordinate.xy + vec2(pw*w,ph*h),blur)*mix(1.0,(float(i))/(float(rings)),bias)*p;
                s += 1.0*mix(1.0,(float(i))/(float(rings)),bias)*p;
            }
        }
        col /= s; //divide by sample count
    }

    if (showFocus)
    {
        col = debugFocus(col, blur, depth);
    }

    if (vignetting)
    {
        col *= vignette();
    }

    gl_FragColor.rgb = col;
    gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

This is my bokeh filter, a subclass of GPUImageTwoInputFilter:

```
@implementation GPUImageBokehFilter

- (id)init;
{
    NSString *fragmentShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BokehShader" ofType:@"fsh"];
    NSString *fragmentShaderString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fragmentShaderPathname encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    if (!(self = [super initWithFragmentShaderFromString:fragmentShaderString]))
    {
        return nil;
    }

    focalDepthUniform = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"focalDepth"];
    focalLengthUniform = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"focalLength"];
    fStopUniform = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"fstop"];

    [self setFocalDepth:1.0];
    [self setFocalLength:35.0];
    [self setFStop:2.2];

    return self;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Accessors

- (void)setFocalDepth:(float)focalDepth {
    _focalDepth = focalDepth;
    [self setFloat:_focalDepth forUniform:focalDepthUniform program:filterProgram];
}

- (void)setFocalLength:(float)focalLength {
    _focalLength = focalLength;
    [self setFloat:_focalLength forUniform:focalLengthUniform program:filterProgram];
}

- (void)setFStop:(CGFloat)fStop {
    _fStop = fStop;
    [self setFloat:_fStop forUniform:fStopUniform program:filterProgram];
}

@end
```

And finally, this is how I use said filter:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    GPUImageBokehFilter *bokehFilter;
    GPUImagePicture *bokehMap;
    UIImage *inputImage;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stones"];
    bokehMap = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bokehmask"]];
    _backgroundImage.image = inputImage;

    bokehFilter = [[GPUImageBokehFilter alloc] init];

    [self processImage];
}
- (IBAction)dataInputUpdated:(id)sender {
    [self processImage];
}
- (void *)processImage {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        GPUImagePicture *gpuPicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage];
        [gpuPicture addTarget:bokehFilter];
        [gpuPicture processImage];
        [bokehMap addTarget:bokehFilter];
        [bokehMap processImage];
        [bokehFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
        [bokehFilter setFloat:inputImage.size.width forUniformName:@"inputImageTextureWidth"];
        [bokehFilter setFloat:inputImage.size.height forUniformName:@"inputImageTextureHeight"];

        UIImage *blurredImage = [bokehFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self displayNewImage:blurredImage];
        });
    });
}
- (void)displayNewImage:(UIImage*)newImage {
    [UIView transitionWithView:_backgroundImage
                      duration:.6f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        _backgroundImage.image = newImage;
                    } completion:nil];
}

...
```

The first image is the one I'm trying to blur, the second one is a random gradient to test the shader's depth map thingy:

[image: stones]
[image: bokehmask]

When I start the app on my iPhone, I get this:

[image: Weird shader result 1]

After moving the slider (which triggers the dataInputChanged method), I get this:

[image: Weird shader result 2, feat. diagonal noisy line]

While that admittedly looks much better than the first image, I still have some problems with this:

1. There's a diagonal noisy line (inside the red lines I put on the picture) that appears to be unblurred.
2. The top left of the image is blurry, even though it shouldn't be.

Why do I get this weird behavior? Shouldn't the shader output be the same every time?
Also, how do I get it to respect the depth map? My GLSL shader knowledge is very limited, so please be patient.

Comment: The first thing that leaps out at me is that `[bokehMap processImage];` and `[bokehFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];` are in the wrong order. They need to be flipped, so that you tell the filter you will be capturing from it before you trigger the processing that updates the filter output. Try switching those and see what happens. Aside from that, this is a horribly expensive shader, and I wonder if replacing it with a three-input filter that also takes in a Gaussian-blurred version of the image for mixing (like tilt shift does) would work better.

Comment: I flipped the two method calls, only to get the same results. Also, I know that this shader is expensive, but I don't know enough about shaders to simplify it. It's a miracle that I managed to get this far without help! :D It'd be great if someone who knows what they're doing took this, cleaned it up and made it an 'official' part of GPUImage.

Comment: (Also, keep up the great work! GPUImage made me learn the basics of fragment shaders, something I've been putting off for far too long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers helped me get on the right track, and after a few hours of fiddling around with my code and the shader, I managed to get all bugs fixed. Here's what caused them and how I fixed them:

The ugly diagonal line was caused by the `linearize()` method, so I removed it and made the shader use the RGB values (or, to be more precise: only the R value) from the depth map without processing them first.

The blue-ish image I got from the shader was caused by my own incompetence. These two lines had to be put *before* the calls to `processImage`:

```
[bokehFilter setFloat:inputImage.size.width forUniformName:@"inputImageTextureWidth"];
[bokehFilter setFloat:inputImage.size.height forUniformName:@"inputImageTextureHeight"];
```

In hindsight, it's obvious why I only got results the second time I used the shader. After fixing those bugs, I went on to optimize it a bit to keep the execution time as low as possible, and now I can tell it to render 8 samples/4 rings and it does so in less than a second. Here's what that looks like:

[image: How the shader's output should look like]

Thanks for the answers, everyone, I probably wouldn't have gotten those bugs fixed without you.

Answer (score 4):

The diagonal artifact appears to be caused by your test gradient.  You can see that it occurs at about the same place as where your gradient goes to completely white.  Try spreading out the gradient so it only reaches 1.0 or 0.0 at the very corners of the image.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of having a depth map in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean?  I'm saying you still use a gradient, just don't make it clamp to 1.0 or 0.0 in the middle of the image.  Try overlaying your gradient (in photoshop or something) on your image;  you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I need those solid white/black areas because they tell the shader what to fully keep in focus and what to blur. If I follow your advice, the shader blurs everything except a very little part in the image's corner where the gradient reaches 1.0.

Comment: Oh, ok.  I don't understand the shader well enough to know specifically why, but the shape of the gradient is definitely what's causing the artifact -- there's an "edge" as the gradient approaches 0.0 or 1.0.  If you think about it as signal processing, edges are high-frequency changes.  The shader needs to filter them out; the shader needs to sample more around each point.  To avoid that change, you could try a smooth gradient (instead of a linear one); an S-curve gradient (I forget what that's called at the moment).

Comment: You could use an RGB depth map and get 16777216 gradations instead of just 256.

Comment: I'll say.  I've spend days working on stuff like this for an app.  Trying to find the culprit when things aren't going right.  I think anna is on to something.  I can't tell which part of the image is blurred and which part isn't.  I'd set the amount way up so you can really tell.  Or use a color overlay instead of a blur to see that your depth buffer code is even right.  Did you write all this code or find it somewhere? Cause to me it seems like a formula is wrong or maybe a precision hint is off.

Comment: Turns out that the linearize() function was responsible for the artifact. I removed it and the artifact was gone.

Answer (score 4):

It's a pretty big question, and I can't make a full answer because I would really need to test the thing out.

But a few points: The final image that you put up is hard to work with.  Because the image has been upscaled so much, I can't tell if it's actually blurred or if it just appears blurry because of the resolution.  Regardless, the amount of blur that you're getting (when compared to the original link that you provided) suggests that something isn't working with the shader.

Another thing that concerns me is the `//some optimization thingy` comment that you've got in there.  This is the sort of thing that's going to be responsible for an ugly line in your final output.  Saying that you wont have any blur under `blur < 0.05` isn't necessarily something that you can do!  I would be expecting a nasty artifact as the shader transitions from the blur shader and into the 'optimized' part.

Hope that sheds some light, and good luck!

Comment: The optimization thingy is actually quite helpful, as it basically keeps the shader from processing image parts that aren't meant to be processed. It helps that the transition from 0.05% blur to 0% blur is pretty much invisible.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried enabling `showFocus`? This should show the focal point in red and the focal range in green which should help with debugging. You could also try enabling `autofocus` to ensure that the centre of the image is in focus, because at the moment it's not obvious which distance should be in focus, due to the `linearize` function changing coordinate systems. After that try tweaking `fstop` to get the desired amount of blur. You will probably also find that you will need greater than `samples = 3` and `rings = 3` to produce a smooth bokeh effect.